# Site design - icon on Achievements list

Tags: bug, design

The icon on the Achievements list, scaled down from the standard logo, looks like a piece of fruit, not the intended planet.

[image: Cropped screenshot of the open Achievements list]

The screenshot is enlarged when I view the image in a message, so go get the real idea look at this so the picture is about 2" wide at reading distance.

Comment: Idk, I kinda like it. After all, we _know_ what it actually is. So, if you don't like it, what do you suggest? A bigger planet? That it be flanked by the letters W and B? Give us some options to debate

Comment: The icon already got adjusted slightly to make the silhouette clearer, I think maybe more could be done along those lines. Possibly just making the rings black or something.

Comment: The same thing happened to Puzzling.

Comment: Perhaps because the ring on the right looks the same shade as the shadow on the left, so it makes the whole thing look like a solid shape.